# Copy data from vb.net datagrid into excel using sendkeys

Tags: excel, vba, datagrid

I Have this code in VBA as a macro

```
Sub Test()
Dim Wkb As Workbook

Set Wkb = ActiveWorkbook
notepadID = Shell("C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\TestInstaller\TestApp.exe")

SendKeys "admin", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "nothing", True
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
SendKeys "^C"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
AppActivate "MicroSoft Excel"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
SendKeys "^V"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))



End Sub
```

So what i'm trying to do is copy data from a datagrid to excel, but i'm having trouble with just trying to copy the 1st cell of the datagrid, but when i try to paste it manually, the data is there! what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right after

```
SendKeys "^C"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
```

try using

```
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
```

instead of

```
AppActivate "MicroSoft Excel"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
SendKeys "^V"
```

Comment: Sir I could paste the content of the first data grid, i could copy AND paste the 2nd cell of the datagrid however.

Comment: so what can you NOT do?

Comment: the 1st grid sir, its funny because i cant copy the first grid, but when you try it manually, the value of the 1st grid is in the clipboard, but, when for the send keys of the 2nd grid value, it does copy!

Comment: Oops, my bad. I did not tried your code. Thanks btw!